# using lines of output as an array in bash

Tags: bash

I have a mysql database on a shared web host. It's grown too large, and a single dump process with zipping is getting killed. I want to dump and zip each table in individually. With this command

```
mysqldump -uuser -ppass database < show_tables.sql
```

I can get it to return all the names of the tables like so:

```
table1
table2
etc
...
```

How can I feed this into a bash script so that I can feed each line into a command of this syntax

```
mysqldump -uuser -ppass database table_name_goes_here > and_here.sql
```

?

**Edit** Sorry folks, I made a mistake in the original formatting. The output from the `show tables` query is not a single line with space-delimited table names; it is actually one table name per line, as it is formatted now. I apologize for the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mysqldump -uuser -ppass database < show_tables.sql |
xargs -I TableName sh -c 'mysqldump -uuser -ppass database TableName > TableName.sql'
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the table names cannot contain newlines,

```
mysqldump -uuser -ppass database < show_tables.sql | 
while IFS= read -r table; do
        mysqldump -uuser -ppass database "$table" > and_here.sql
done
```

Comment: That's only any good if the output is null-delimited.

Comment: @Mikel Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean.  The output of the first command has to be newline delimited.  The output of the second one can be anything it likes.

Comment: @Mikel: It won't work if each table name is null-delimited. `read` reads up to a newline, regardless of how  `IFS` is set ..`IFS` only tells `read`  how to split up what it reads (based on `-d` which is `\n` by default).. `read` doesn't need `IFS` at all when reading just a single var (`$table`).. Really, for just a single var, the only time you need `IFS=` is when you want to cater for embedded `\n`, in which case you must have null-delimited input and `IFS= read -d $'\0'`.. The following works fine without a modified IFS: `printf "a  b\nx  y\n" |while read -r x; do echo $((i+=1))"$x="; done`

Comment: `IFS=` prevents `read` from stripping leading and trailing whitespace (try `read -r a <<<'  foo  '` vs `IFS= read -r a <<<'  foo  '`).  If the table names don't have such things then it won't make a difference, but I threw it in for safety in case they do.

Comment: Thanks jw013, I had forgotten all about the lead/trail whitespace. I wonder if that behaviour existed originally for interactive input... `"for safety";` a good ethos... I do usually use `-r`, and even `set -f` to 
disable globbing. I'll now make sure I *usually* use `IFS=`

Comment: @jw013 you're right.

Comment: Looks like `mysql -Bse` produces output that's easier to parse.  It also uses C-style escapes, so maybe you don't want the `-r` option to `read`.

Answer (score 2):

The [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arrays) says

```
   Arrays are assigned to using compound assignments of the form name=(value1 ... valuen),
```

so you just need a way put your command's output where it says `value1 ... valuen`.

You can do that like this

```
databases=( $(mysqldump -uuser -ppass database < show_tables.sql) )
```

and then iterate over them like this

```
for database in ${databases[*]}; do
    ...
done
```

but just in case your table name is really weird and contains some newlines, I'd recommend using `mysql -Bse` to list the databases and/or tables, and use `while read IFS=` like jw013 suggests (possibly without the `-r` option).

Comment: It should be mentioned that the command substitution approach requires the table names to not contain any whitespace characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql database -e 'show tables' | while read table
do mysqldump -uuser -ppass database "$table" -r "$table.sql"
done
```

Works with spaces in the tables, too.

Comment: That would include some header lines like `----------`.  Add the `-B` option to turn those off.  Also, how is your answer different from jw013's?

Comment: If you have an improvement to make, edit the post.